# regular expressions rel tags

Tags: regex

I want to use regular expression to grab the url from a html css link tag from the HTML source code

eg

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="http://sample.com/icons/apple-touch-icon.png">
```

any help??

Comment: see [this blog by Jeff Atwood](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)

Answer (score 4):

**Standard response:** Do not use regexes to read XML and especially not HTML. Use a HTML parser.

Realistic response: if the input you're working with is **consistent** and **predictable**, then this may work for you:

```
/<link\s+rel="([^"]*)"/
```

If the input varies virtually *at all* from the example in your question, this will break. The following are examples of valid HTML which will not work with the regex:

```
<link rel=apple-touch-icon>
<link rel='apple-touch-icon'>
<link href='...' rel='apple'>
<link
   rel="apple">
<link rel = "apple">
```

etc, etc... You *could* try extending the regex to cater for some of these, but you'd be entering a world of hurt.

*edit*: sorry, I just noticed that you wanted the `href`. The above still applies, just replace 'rel' with 'href' as necessary.